# Find and delete with nano

Tags: nano

I want to find specific characters/strings with nano and delete all occurrences. How can this be done with nano and can this even be done?

Answer (score 5):

##### Find and Replace

This use of "Find and Replace" works in Nano 5.8: (I have tested)

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (default keybinding)
- `Search (to replace):` Enter the *string* you want to search for, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `Replace with:` Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (leaving the replace string blank)
- `Replace this instance?` Press <kbd>A</kbd> to repace all instances of *string* with no characters (thus removing it)

##### Upgrade Nano to a newer version (for 20.04 LTS)

There are 2 options: (I have tested both)

1. Uninstall the `deb` version of Nano, and install the `snap` version (currently 5.7): `sudo snap install nano --classic`
2. Download a newer and compatible [Debian package](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/nano_5.4-2_amd64.deb.html) (currently 5.4 available) and install: `sudo apt install ./nano_5.4-2_amd64.deb`

Comment: I already tried this. Unfortunately, it didn't work. All occurrences were replaced with a space instead of being removed.

Comment: Which version of Nano are you using? I've tested on 5.8 and it works.

Comment: Then you most likely did type a space char at the "Replace with:" prompt. Nano is well behaved IMO.

Comment: I think I know the problem. I think it did remove the characters. I had multiple lines and each of them contained one character. I wanted to remove the line but it did just remove the characters and not the line break.

Comment: Yeah OK, I don't think you can search and replace line breaks with Nano.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes you can (but not by default without external commands)! :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959610/nano-insert-newline-in-search-and-replace/73945051#73945051 (This describes how to make a keyboard shortcut that lets you do Python-style regular expression substitutions, which allow searching/replacing new lines).

Comment: Interesting ... 

Comment: If you don't need full regular expressions, in the Python file mentioned in my answer I linked to above, you could replace `re.sub(regex, replacement, myString) with myString.replace(searchCriteria, replacement)`, and it'll still do new lines (without having to use regular expressions).